# PHP/mysqli - prepared statement (in a loop) or multi_query

Tags: php, mysqli, mysqli-multi-query

I've just moved on from using mysql to mysqli extension in PHP.

I've come across two ways of doing the same thing (multiple update queries), what are the pros/cons of each? Should I be using one or the other or something else entirely?

Prepared statement in a loop:

```
//prepare statement
foreach(whatever){
  //execute statement
}
```

or

Multi-query:

```
foreach(whatever){
  //build many queries into a single string
}
multi_query(long string)
```

I know that prepared statements offer better security.
When using mysql in PHP I've heard its best to avoid using UPDATE statements in a loop - isn't executing a mysqli prepared statement in a loop the same thing by another name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If for some reason you can't update all targeted records with just a single mysql update statement to avoid the need for this this PHP loop altogether, it's perfectly fine reusing this same `update` mysqli statement object in a loop.

Style and resource-wise, reusing your parameterized statement is best rather than constantly recreating it.  By reusing it, all you're doing after the initial `bind_param` call is re-assigning the value of the bound PHP variables on each iteration, then simply re-`executing` (See: *[`mysqli_stmt->execute` Example #1 Object oriented style](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php)*).

Remember, in your `WHERE` clause, you'd just have another PHP variable-assigned parameter like `WHERE (recordID = ?)` to iterate over.

It takes extra resources to initially set up each parameterized statement, so multiple parameterized statements should be reserved for passing in multiple *unrelated* statements or queries.  Also, it does not appear that PHP's `multi queries` functions and methods support parameterization at all anyway.

Answer (score 7):

The other two answers do *not* address the actual differences between multi-query and prepared statements - they are completely different.

- Prepared statements - you create a statement template *once* then execute it multiple times with different values used for each template (using bind_param). There is a server round-trip for setting up the statement *and* one round-trip per query. It uses MySQL's binary protocol to send data, so it will actually be sending less data through the lines than a normal query.
- Multi-query - This is simply executing multiple normal MySQL queries all at once. There is *one* server round-trip for the whole multi-query. This almost definitely provides better performance compared prepared statements (unless your query is abnormally gigantic and the changing values are small).

So I would recommend mutli-query for speed. Its no less secure if you properly escape your data with mysqli::real_escape_string. Another benefit of multi-query is that you can do completely different queries all in the same request - while prepared statements rely on query symmetry to provide any benefit.

Answer (score 0):

bob-the-destroyer is right (better to use prepared statements). I just wanted to add a few things.

1. executing `$mysqli->multi_query($sql)` after the loop is equivalent to execute `$mysqli->query($sql)` every time inside the loop. The difference between `multi_query` and just `query` is that `query` doesn't accept more than 1 query separated by semicolons. multi_query does make it a little more difficult to check for errors on the second and following queries executed.
2. I don't know why someone would avoid issuing UPDATEs inside a loop. But it is best practice to wrap the loop in a transaction so if any query fails you can rollback all the updates.

Comment: performance-wise, $mysqli->multi_query($sql) is not entirely equivalent to executing $mysql->query($sql) inside a loop because running $mysql->query multiple times will cause multiple server round-trips which makes the latter slower.

Comment: multi_query is a lot better for a large amount of inserts. I used $mysqli->query($sql) for 10 000 of insert and it takes 2 minutes. The same inserts with multi_query takes 20 sec. So for big amount of insert use multi_query.